# Custom app disappears after spotify restart

Tags: api, spotify, sidebar

is it normal that I have to search "spotify:app:$FOLDERNAME" after each restart of spotify to get my app active again even I "added my application to the sidebar"?

Other apps installed by the App Finder are kept as expected.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The manifest from local apps are read at start. The client removes apps from the sidebar that are not available in the finder.

Comment: Is it possible to change this behavior? What about personal apps which are not built to be published?

Comment: Yes. We will change the behavior. I don't have an estimate on when this will be introduced.

Comment: Custom apps seem to be persisting in the sidebar now (as of June 1), although my client version hasn't changed (0.8.3.222.g317ab79d).

Comment: I'm using version 0.9.7.16.g (i like the old design) and i have to reinstall my app every single time i restart spotify.. this stinks! i don't want to upgrade, is there any way to make my app stick?