# Home made Spotify app disappears after restart

Tags: spotify

I've just started developing my first Spotify app. I manage to get it working and I can also add it as a "Favorite" so it appears under Apps in the menu.

But every time I restart Spotify it disappears! Does anybody have a solution?

I've also tried to add the Spotify Apps Tutorial app and made it a favorite and it keeps disappearing as well.

The same question was posted over a year ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059013/custom-app-disappears-after-spotify-restart/) without a complete answer so I thought that somebody might have a solution now!

Best regards

Björn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour now is the same as it was then — since the apps list is synchronised across your account (i.e., adding an app to your favourites on one machine will have it show up on another machine logged into your account), bundle IDs that aren't in the App Finder don't get saved.